# Try to get Javascript functions to run Synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, rsvp.js, rsvp-promise

I'm having trouble with the following code snippet.  My init method needs to run and complete the getLocation() function before the initializeMapp() and geoListen() can run.  I have rsvp.js linked as a resource, but not quite sure how to implement.  I also tried the jQuery $when.done method.   Any help is appreciated.

jQuery Method:

```
//initial page load method
function init() {

    //get user location then builds map and listens to database
    $.when(getLocation()).done.(function () {

       //build map now that you have user location
        initializeMap();

       //Starts listening to database changes
       geoListen();

    })

}
```

RSVP method:

```
 //initial page load method
 function init() {

      //get user location then builds map and listens to database
     getLocation().then(function () {

     //build map now that you have user location
     initializeMap();

     //Starts listening to database changes
     geoListen();

  })

 }
```

Comment: What happened exactly when you ran those code snippets? What does `getLocation()` return?

Comment: Does getLocation return a promise?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your `getLocation` function accept callbacks and execute them when `getLocation` finishes

```
getLocation = function(cb1, cb2) {
  // when done 
  cb1()
  cb2()
}

function init() {
  getLocation(initializeMap, geoListen)
}
```

or you can pass an array of callback references and loop through them in `getLocation` and call them

alternatively you can use  Q.js and return a promise from `getLocation`

Comment: Shouldn't need to do this if getLocation returns a promise.